# What is slot in shader editor

Tags: shaders

[image]

When I try to change material using that button I doesn't change sometime. Doing the changes in slot it works. Can you explain me what is slot and what relation it has with changing materials?
I have tried to read with documentation but as beginner I find it difficult to understand

Comment: I'm talking about Slot and button I marked using arrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slots are for giving different faces different material, all in the same object. If you have only one slot, you can use the button you marked to give your object material.

[image: Slots]

In Edit Mode you can select faces and assing them to certain slots. Lets say you want two slots. You press the little down arrow next to Slot 1 and press <kbd>+</kbd> to add a new slot. Select a face, select slot 2 and press assign. Now you can give the selected face different material by pressing the button you marked.

Answer (score 4):

The button you are showing gives you access to all the materials you have created within your file, it allows you to assign the material you want to the selected slot on the left.

In the material list that you find in the *Properties panel > Material*, you’ll see, for the selected object, what materials are assigned to slot 1, 2, etc. Here, I've created 2 slots, the yellow material is assigned to slot 1, the blue is assigned to slot 2.

Let’s say that, in *Edit* mode, I’ve assigned the material that is in slot 1 (here, yellow) to all the faces of the object:

[image]

If I want I can change the color of slot 1 to another one, here red. As the material that has been assigned to the object is the one on slot 1, the object becomes red:

[image]